# OpenCv Troubleshooting (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, calibration

```
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

cv::Mat src=imread("/home/cdukunlu/Downloads/EuFFJ.jpg");

float data[9]= {161.837869,0.059269,319.778713,0.000000,165.648492,230.424626,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000};
float rectification[9]={1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000,0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,1.000000};
cv::Vec<float,4> k(0.148201,-0.031856,0.012784,-0.003392);

cv::Mat F = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, data);
cv::Mat R = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32FC1, rectification);

std::cout<<"Calibrationg..."<<std::endl;


    cv::Size size = {src.cols, src.rows};

    cv::Mat K(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    K.at<double>(0, 0) = 1307.2807020496643;
    K.at<double>(0, 1) = 0.0;
    K.at<double>(0, 2) = 530.3754311563506;

    K.at<double>(1, 0) = 0.0;
    K.at<double>(1, 1) = 1318.342691460933;
    K.at<double>(1, 2) = 354.98352268131123;

    K.at<double>(2, 0) = 0.0;
    K.at<double>(2, 1) = 0.0;
    K.at<double>(2, 2) = 1.0;

    cv::Mat D(4, 1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
    D.at<double>(0, 0) = -0.2994762856767568;
    D.at<double>(1, 0) = 0.5036082961388784;
    D.at<double>(2, 0) = -4.231072729639434;
    D.at<double>(3, 0) = 3.8646397788794578;
    cv::Mat E = cv::Mat::eye(3, 3, cv::DataType<double>::type);

    cv::Mat map1;
    cv::Mat map2;

    std::cout << K << std::endl;
    std::cout << D << std::endl;
    std::cout << E << std::endl;
    std::cout << size << std::endl;

    cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, E, K, size, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
```

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.5.5-pre) /home/cdukunlu/opencv_build/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 61343654331232 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
```

What could be causing such situation?

Comment: Use a debugger and take a look at the stack trace so you can see what call in your code triggers the crash. Looks like you have a very high number somewhere around when allocation a buffer.

Comment: You have an exception, add try / catch to know in which line exception is raised, and then focus on this line.

Comment: I suppose that your image isn't loaded so size contain uninitialized values. Then, in initUndistortRectifyMap it tries to allocate matrices with size that is enormously big due to uninitialized content of size variable.

Comment: I had used debugger and cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, E, K, size, CV_16SC2, map1, map2); function is causing the crash.

Comment: Also ı had checked the value of image and it seems like it is initialized but still no work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem with checking the opencv libraries.

Since ı had two different libraries installed to my ubuntu; the precompiled version of OpenCV version is 3.x but my code is tested on different version of opencv which it is OpenCV 4.5.2

As soon as ı had changed the version from 3.x to 4.5.2 the problem has gone.

After all it would be good to use only one version of libraries to avoid bugs.